# wait for function and then console result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops

I want to wait for my functions like fetching all result first, then consoling my result.

```
exports.listofAllFeaturedProd = (req, res) => {

  Product.find({is_featured:'1'},function(error,fetchallFeatProds)
  {

    var allProducts = new Array();
    var pp = 0;
    var products  = new Array();
    for (var ProductId in fetchallFeatProds)
    {
        var pArr            = [];
        pArr['_id']         = fetchallFeatProds[ProductId]._id;
        pArr['name']        = fetchallFeatProds[ProductId].name;
        pArr['sku']         = fetchallFeatProds[ProductId].sku;
        pArr['description'] = fetchallFeatProds[ProductId].description;
        pArr['price']       = fetchallFeatProds[ProductId].price;
        pArr['large_image'] = fetchingImage(fetchallFeatProds[ProductId]._id);
        pArr['brand']       = fetchingBrand(fetchallFeatProds[ProductId].brand_id);

        console.log('#################### IMAGE ####################');   
        console.log(pArr); 
    pp++;
    }
    console.log(products); 

  });

}; 


function fetchingImage(pid)
{
  ProductImage.findOne({product_id:pid},function(error,fetchallFeatProdsImgs)
  {
    console.log(fetchallFeatProdsImgs.large_image);
     return fetchallFeatProdsImgs.large_image;
  });
}

function fetchingBrand(bid)
{
  Brand.findOne({_id:bid},function(error,fetchAllBrands)
  { 
    console.log(fetchAllBrands);
      return fetchAllBrands;

  });
}
```

node not wait for functions and console undefined after that console my function result. how i stop my code for fetching first result then console all data in array.

Output for `console.log(pArr);`

```
[ _id: 57bd996ebf8c930b2bcc06a1,
  name: 'New Product',
  sku: 'New-Product',
  description: 'New Product',
  price: 'test',
  large_image: undefined,
  brand: undefined ]
```

After that added console inside functions which gave results as below:

Output for `fetchingImage`

```
images/12.png
```

Output for `fetchingBrand`

```
{ user_id: '57b42b571fc35e49162de413',
  brand_name: '10 Fork ',
  brand_logo: 'uploads/brands_logo/1472027911329_5.png',
  brand_desc: '10 Fork',
  _id: 57bd5ce6cebed2a3189cedcf,
  __v: 0 }
```

Desired output is:

```
[ _id: 57bd996ebf8c930b2bcc06a1,
  name: 'New Product',
  sku: 'New-Product',
  description: 'New Product',
  price: 'test',
  large_image: images/12.png,
  brand: { user_id: '57b42b571fc35e49162de413',
           brand_name: '10 Fork ',
           brand_logo: 'uploads/brands_logo/1472027911329_5.png',
           brand_desc: '10 Fork',
           _id: 57bd5ce6cebed2a3189cedcf,
           __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: Try using `async` in your code. Which may help you solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
var temp = [], 
     async = require('async');

async.eachSeries(fetchallFeatProds, function(ProductId, callback)
{
   pArr['_id']         = ProductId._id;
   pArr['name']        = ProductId.name;
   pArr['sku']         = ProductId.sku;
   pArr['description'] = ProductId.description;
   pArr['price']       = ProductId.price;
   pArr['large_image'] = fetchingImage(ProductId._id);
   pArr['brand']       = fetchingBrand(ProductId.brand_id);

   temp.push(pArr);
   callback(null);
}, function(err){
    console.log(temp); //This should give you desired result
});
```

If it is not working still, try using `callback`for the functions `fetchingImage` and `fetchingBrand`. Or you may try using `async.parallel` as well inside `eachSeries`.

EDIT:-

[async-eachseries](https://github.com/async-js/async#async.eachseries)

Change your functions with `callback`.

```
function fetchingImage(pid, callback)
{
    ProductImage.findOne({product_id:pid},function(error,fetchallFeatProdsImgs)
   {
      console.log(fetchallFeatProdsImgs.large_image);
     callback(error,fetchallFeatProdsImgs.large_image);
   });
}

function fetchingBrand(bid, callback)
{
    Brand.findOne({_id:bid},function(error,fetchAllBrands)
    { 
       console.log(fetchAllBrands);
       calback(error,fetchAllBrands);
   });
}
```

Use `async.parallel` so that it will wait till both the functions are done. Then push into `temp` array. [Doc to refer](https://github.com/async-js/async#async.parallel)

```
async.eachSeries(fetchallFeatProds, function(ProductId, callback)
{
   var pArr  = {};
   pArr['_id']         = ProductId._id;
   pArr['name']        = ProductId.name;
   pArr['sku']         = ProductId.sku;
   pArr['description'] = ProductId.description;
   pArr['price']       = ProductId.price;
   async.parallel([
     function(callback)
     {
          fetchingImage(ProductId._id, function(err, res){
         pArr['large_image'] = res;
         callback(err); //Forgot to add
      });
   },
    function(callback)
   {
      fetchingBrand(ProductId.brand_id,function(err, res){
         pArr['brand'] = res;
         callback(err); //Forgot to add
      });
   },
], function(err){

   console.log(pArr); //Edit
   temp.push(pArr);
   callback(err); 
})
  }, function(err){
    console.log(temp); //This should give you desired result
    callback(err);
});
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how i put exactly your code in my code because i am new in node.js. I have tried to put your code in under for loop.

Comment: No. Replace the code of for loop. Don't put inside for.

Comment: Make sure you have `async` in node modules.

Comment: { _id: 57bd996ebf8c930b2bcc06a1,
    name: 'New Product',
    sku: 'New-Product',
    description: 'New Product',
    price: '123',
    large_image: undefined,
    brand: undefined }

Comment: Ok. Issue is still there seems. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121808/discussion-between-pritesh-mahajan-and-shrabanee).

Comment: Forgot to add `callback(err);` inside `async.parallel`. Now it should work.

Comment: You are my hero (bow)

Comment: Glad to help you. Make sure to read the documents I have given in the answer before using `async`.

Comment: are you there need to talk with you